# Change script output when key pressed while it is running in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to change the output of a script while it is running? 
Lets say I have a script called "numbers" and it is running. The script uses this loop to print numbers from 1 to 49:

```
for ((a=1; a<50; a++))
do
     echo $a
     sleep 1
done
```

How can I change the output of this loop while it is running? Let's say if I press a or b during the running, it should subtract 1 from the result.

Comment: Do you want to increase a variable or decrease ir you press a or b between 1 and 49 or you want to run 50 times for decreasing and increasing?

Comment: This loop will execute instantaneously with no time for the user to do anything. Can you give a more realistic example of what you want to have happen?

Comment: Do you want to **block** until the user inputs something? That is prompt the user to enter *a* or *b* and then do something?

Comment: I have updated my example! What I want is if I press a or any other letter when this is running, the loop should subtract 1, so if number 5 was displayed when I pressed a the loop should go back to 4!

Comment: I don't want to ask user for prompt. That is simple! I want to see how we can change output while script is running, but there is no prompt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments there is no time to do anything during so short a run. But if I make the run longer and slower I can demonstrate something similar to what you're asking.

```
declare -i a b c # Ensure these values are treated as integers
b=1
for ((a=0; a < 10**6; a+=b)); do
    read -s -N1 -t.3 c && b=c
    printf '%d...' "$a"
done
echo
```

Breakdown of `read` arguments:

```
read -s   # Don't echo output
     -N1  # Read one character of input*
     -t.3 # Wait for .3 seconds before giving up
     c &&
b=c # If read was successful, assign value to c, then b
```

Here's some craziness. Enjoy:

```
declare -i a b
b=1
for ((a=0; a < 10**6; a+=b)); do
    if read -s -N1 -t.01 c; then
        case $c in
            j) b=b+1;;
            k) b=b-1;;
        esac
    fi
    printf '%d...' "$a"
done
echo
```

*I noticed that bash v3 seems to use `read -n1` and v4 `read -N1`.

Comment: Thank your for the answer! I am trying to understand how your script works. If I don't understand, I'll ask you!

Comment: @ScottPearce OK, I'll be around.